# comparing two sigma algebras in a non-second countable topological space

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(\Omega,\tau)$ be  a topological space such that $\tau$ is not second countable. Assume $B$ is a base for the $\tau$. We denote $M$ and $M_0$ by the sigma algebra generated by $\tau$ and $B$  respectively.

Q. I feel $M$ and $M_0$ are not the same in general, but have no example. Any suggestion or examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the discrete topology on an uncountable set, with $B$ consisting of all the singletons.  Then $M=P(\Omega)$, but $M_0$ is only the countable and cocountable sets.